# Bernoulli Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bernoulli-polynomials

I'm working through some Bernoulli differential equation exercises and wanted to check my work on one and get some guidance on one that is totally stumping me.

1.) $u' + u = e^xu^4$

Answer:

First, divide both sides by $u^4$, to get $u^{-4}u' + u^{-3} = e^x$

Now, substitute $v = u^{-3}$, and thus $v'= -3u^{-4}u'$

Plugging in and substituting, we get

$-\frac{1}{3}v' + v = e^x$, which means $v' - 3v = -3e^x$

Now we have a much nicer differential equation to work with, and,

$u(x) = e^{-\int-3}[\int e^{\int-3}(-3e^x)dx + c]$

$ = e^{3x}[\int e^{-3x}(-3e^x)dx + c]$

$ = e^{3x}[-3\int e^{-3x}e^xdx + c]$

$ = e^{3x}[-3\int e^{-2x}dx + c]$

$ = e^{3x}[-3(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}) + c]$

$ = e^{3x}[\frac{3}{2}e^{-2x} + c]$ $= \frac{3}{2}e^x + ce^{3x}$

Correct?

2.) $xu' + u = xu'$

This is the one that is really stumping me from the start. I'm not sure where one would begin in order to work this into a simpler differential equation.

Comment: Did you mean $xu'+u=(xu)'$ in 2.)? This is then just the product rule of differentiation.

Comment: In 1.) you have solved the equation for $v$, you did not re-insert $u=v^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, so really the answer is the cube root of 1 over everything I have their. And no, #2 is posed exactly as I see it.

Comment: 2.) Then $u=0$ follows directly, no deep enigmas.

Comment: Yea, that what I though, just seems like a waste of time to pose that question... thanks though!